# Pasar puntero a cadena a una función en C

Tags: c, string, punteros, puntero-a-función

Tengo este programa simple que tiene una puntero a una cadena de caracteres, que es pasado a la funcion "change" y modificado dentro de la funcion por un puntero a puntero. Sin embargo, el programa no funciona correctamente y lanza un segmentation fault al ejecutarlo. Supongo que sigo perteneciendo al club de gente que no entiende los punteros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int change(char **p){
    
    **p="string 2";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *ptr="string";
    printf("%s \n", ptr);
    change(&ptr);
    printf("%s \n", ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string                                                                                                                               
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `**p="string 2";` -> `warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer`. En otras palabras: **te sobra un `*`**

Comment: @juanjo gracias, era eso. Mala costumbre de ignorar los warnings a veces.

Comment: **Muy** mala costumbre :-)